# why does not execute statement query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have write below query in function which executes through trigger.

```
SELECT report_date INTO logdate FROM agent_statistics WHERE agentid =             
    NEW.caller_id_name AND report_date = DATE(NEW.start_stamp);
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO outbound FROM cdr WHERE (caller_id_name = 
    NEW.caller_id_name AND direction = 'outbound' AND 
    DATE(NEW.start_stamp) = logdate);
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO consult FROM cdr WHERE (caller_id_name =
    NEW.caller_id_name AND direction = 'outbound' AND 
    DATE(NEW.start_stamp) = logdate AND billsec > '0');
```

Here, logdate value gives proper date. But, outbound and consult gives all rows from table. means previous date also include which is not to include.
I need only current date total rows.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `billsec` is a number, don't compare it with a string `'0'` is string value, `0` is a number.

Comment: In select query i test it, without quotes it gives error. so, i put that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your `DATE(NEW.start_stamp) = logdate);`
with `start_stamp = logdate);`